# Can you connect to a db ad-hoc without using the standard configuration method?

Tags: php, laravel, database-connection, laravel-7, dbconnection

## Scenario

Imagine you have a SaaS product which allows users to connect to their db, perform some actions, and then disconnect. They can connect to any db so long as they have the credentials.

## Issue

In Laravel, from my research, it seems that you can only connect to a db using the config file `config/database.php` or the `.env` file and then switch connections programmatically by doing:

```
$dbFoo = DB::connection('foo');
$dbBar = DB::connection('bar');
$dbBaz = DB::connection('baz');
```

My issue is that I need to be able to ad-hoc connect to various databases concurrently based on user input so using the above methods are not possible.

So, what are my options here?

Comment: So why not just creating the connection config on the fly, using `config();`?

Comment: @ITDesigns.eu would that not permanently store than connection in the file? Or, is that temporary?

Comment: I am quite sure it's not permanent :D

Comment: @ITDesigns.eu I should clarify that by permanent I meant that does it write those connection details to the actual file or does it merely store the new values in memory as part of the config file? If it's simply in memory then that'd work, I think.

Comment: There is not native way to rewrite laravel config file, don't worry. Your changed values will be kept only until script shutdown()

Comment: @ITDesigns.eu feel free to write an answer and I'll give it a go and accept if need be.

Comment: Did it work? :)

Comment: @ITDesigns.eu I'm away from my laptop at the moment. I'll get back to you tomorrow with a confirmation.

Comment: Good, I will compile you an answer meanwhile, the way I see it...

Answer (score 1):

In your database.php, you could define your connection like this:

```php
'connections' => [
        'dynamic' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_DEFAULT_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DEFAULT_SCHEME'),
            'username' => null,
            'password' => null,
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        ]
    ],
```

Then in your controller, you could:

```php
//If you need to override just a few values
config(['database.connections.dynamic.host' => 'new_host']);

//If you rather redeclare the whole thing
$params = [
   'driver' => 'mysql',
   'host' => $host,
   'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
   'database' => $db,
   'username' => $user,
   'password' => $pass,
   'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
];
config(['database.connections.dynamic' => $params]);


$dbBaz = DB::connection('dynamic');
```